# JMeter Reports - Is there a way to graph how many of a certain response code over time?

Tags: jmeter

I have a resource that returns a 202 until a queue is full.  Is there any way to graph the different response codes over time?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "graph"? There are different graphs available even in basic JMeter distribution, are you addressing something in particular, or that's a general question?

Comment: This is now available in the JMeter dashboard. No need to install any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 options:

1. There is [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/) listener available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) - you will need `5 Additional Graphs`

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager]
2. There is a similar graph you can get as a part of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

   [image: JMeter Response Codes over Time]

Answer (score -1):

General answer: no with the JMeter just out of the box - "graph" listeners are kinda very basic.

Although there are options.

E.g. you can add more advanced listener plugin (like GraphsGeneratorListener, [here's](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) one of the tutorials).

Or you can stream your results using Backend Listener & Graphite protocol, to some time-series capable DB (like, Influx) and then feed an advanced graphic visualizer (like, Grafana) from there - and show literally whatever you want.
Check [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) as a starting point